# Como simular um form action=POST com urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu quero criar um programa que faça a leitura de minhas notas da faculdade e exiba na tela , para isso estou usando o urllib2 para receber a pagina web onde minhas notas são apresentadas porem para receber eu preciso me logar.

codigo em que estou tentando simular o submit do form e retornar a pagina que ele me redireciona.

```
from urllib2 import *
import urllib
proxy = ProxyHandler({'http': r'http://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx@xxxxx:xxxxxx'})
auth = HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = build_opener(proxy, auth, HTTPHandler)
install_opener(opener)

data = urllib.urlencode({'__EVENTTARGET':'','__EVENTARGUMENT':'','__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA=='
                  ,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'7C9DFC57'
                  ,'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox':"12345"
                  ,"ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox":"12345"
                  ,'submit':'Entrar'})

url = 'http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx'
response = urlopen(url, data).read()
print response
```

o form da pagina web que e para eu me logar e me redireciona para as notas

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA==">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="7C9DFC57">
    <input name="ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox" type="text" id="ctl00_FormularioContentPlaceHolder_UsuarioTextBox" class="caixaTexto">
    <input name="ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox" type="password" id="ctl00_FormularioContentPlaceHolder_SenhaTextBox" class="caixaTexto"></td>
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton" value="Entrar" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_FormularioContentPlaceHolder_EntrarButton" class="botao">&nbsp; <a href="EsqueceuSenha.aspx" id="ctl00_FormularioContentPlaceHolder_LinkExibeEsqueceusenha" class="link">Esqueceu sua senha?</a></td>
```

e esta pagina me direciona para a de login.
Estou tentando me logar porem nao estou tendo sucesso, sera que alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você sabe quais os campos do formulário devem ser preenchidos?

Comment: @qmechanik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632067/how-to-simulate-form-action-post-in-urllib2?noredirect=1#comment47407254_29632067

Comment: sei sim, nesta pergunta que comentei acima fui eu que fiz e esta mais atualizada ...

Comment: Talvez o que esteja atrapalhando seja o *proxy*, há necessidade de usa-lo?

Comment: Necessidade nao porem para testat eu precisava usar pois me encontrava em uma rede fechada com proxy no trabalho por usuario e senha. Testarei de casa , de qlquer forma ja tenho uns 2 modos prontos com urllib2 e requests module, testarei ambos em casa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não deve estar conseguindo logar-se porque está sendo declarado o [*input type*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) do botão, e não o nome.

```all
data = urllib.urlencode({'__EVENTTARGET':'','__EVENTARGUMENT':'','__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA=='
     ,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'7C9DFC57'
     ,'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox':"12345"
     ,"ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox":"12345"
     ,'submit':'Entrar'}) # <------ Errado
```

O correto deveria ser:

```all
data = urllib.urlencode({'__EVENTTARGET':'','__EVENTARGUMENT':'','__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA=='
     ,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'7C9DFC57'
     ,'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox':"12345"
     ,"ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox":"12345"
     ,'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton':'Entrar'}) # <------ Certo
```

O código deve ficar parecido com isto:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib2 import *
import urllib, cookielib

def obterNotas(url, usuario, senha):
    proxy = ProxyHandler({'http': "xxxx.xxxx:zzzz"})
    auth = HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = build_opener(proxy, auth, HTTPHandler, HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
    install_opener(opener)

    dados = urllib.urlencode({'__EVENTTARGET': '',
                         '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                         '__VIEWSTATE': '/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA==',
                         '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'7C9DFC57',
                         'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox': usuario,
                         "ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox": senha,
                         'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton':'Entrar'})
    request = Request(url, dados)
    paginaLogin = urlopen(request).read()
    paginaNotas = None

    # Aqui você verifica se teve sucesso no login
    if 'Algo que indique o sucesso do login' in paginaLogin:
        paginaNotas = urlopen('http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/NotasFaltasTotais.aspx').read()
    return paginaNotas
```

E para usá-la:

```py
def main():
    urlLogin = 'http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx'
    notas = obterNotas(urlLogin, 'usuario', 'senha')
    # Aqui você manipula a variável 'notas' e extrai as informações que você quer
```

<sub>**Nota**: Não testei, provavelmente terá que ser feito alguns *ajustes* para que funcione do modo esperado.</sub>

---

Uma outra alternativa seria usar a biblioteca [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) que permite trabalhar com [`sessões`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), assim facilitando fazer o *LogIn* e obter os dados de uma página que requer autenticação.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

def obterNotas(url, usuario, senha):
    dados = {'__EVENTTARGET': '',
                              '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                              '__VIEWSTATE': '/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA==',
                              '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '7C9DFC57',
                              'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox': usuario,
                              'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox': senha,
                              'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton': 'Entrar'}
    urlNotas = 'http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/NotasFaltasTotais.aspx'

    with requests.Session() as sessao:
        paginaLogin = sessao.post(url, data=dados).text
        paginaNotas = None

        # Aqui você verifica se teve sucesso ao logar
        if 'Algo que indique o sucesso do login' in paginaLogin:
            paginaNotas = sessao.get(urlNotas).text
        return paginaNotas

def main():
    url = 'http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx'
    notas = obterNotas(url, 'usuario','senha')
    # Aqui você manipula a variável 'notas' e extrai as informações que você quer

main()
```

Se for necessário [**utilizar um proxy**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies), basta fazer o seguinte:

```py
import requests

proxy = { "http": "xxxx.xxxx:zzzz", }

requests.get("http://foo.bar.baz", proxies=proxy)
```

Comment: eu consegui realizando o request mais cedo, tive que editar o header da requisicao..

Comment: @user3896400 Funcionou? Eu verifiquei quais informações eram enviadas no `POST`, os valores de `__VIEWSTATE` e `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` são os mesmos que estão na pergunta.

Comment: @user3896400 Se você precisar extrair muitas informações do HTML, pode ser útil usar um *parser* para fazer esse trabalho, por exemplo o [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) serve bem para esse propósito. Se a resposta foi **útil**, positive ela, se for possível marque como **aceita**, clique em ✔, qualquer coisa edito e melhoro a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou.. agora to tentando pesquisar uma substring dentro do html retornado..
preciso formatar uma string ">xxx</a>" = ">__</a>"
independente do valor de x retornar true

Comment: @user3896400 Obrigado! Não entendi ao certo o que você quer fazer, você quer transformar `">xxx</a>"` em `">__</a>"` e depois enviá-lo num `POST`?